# How to append \ join binary digits to a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can i append binary digits to a final variable in python

```
a = self.allcheckboxes[0].isChecked() # 1
b = self.allcheckboxes[1].isChecked() # 0
c = self.allcheckboxes[2].isChecked() # 1
d = self.allcheckboxes[3].isChecked() # 0

final_value = 010+a+b+c+d
# iam expecting something like 0101010 in binary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you just want a binary looking string, rather than an integer with the relevant bits set, if so you could use the following for checkboxes 10 to 14:

```
final_value = ''.join('1' if checkbox.isChecked() else '0' for checkbox in self.allcheckboxes[10:15])
```

This could then be converted to an integer and printed as hex if required as follows:

```
integer_value = int(final_value, 2)
print '{:x}'.format(integer_value)
```

Comment: i have 26 checkboxes but  i want the values only from the self.allcheckboxes[10-14] ,  how can i change it ?

Comment: FWIW, I guess that conditional expression is more readable, but `'01'[checkbox.isChecked()]` is shorter. :)

Comment: that helped me, now can i convert back to hex by using  `print hex(fianl_value)`

Comment: You just need to keep it as an integer value, then you can use `format` to display the integer in hex format. I have updated the answer to show this.

Comment: @SaiGanesh: Using format gives you more control than using `hex()`. You can choose if you want the leading `0x`. And if you use an upper-case 'X' in the format string then the the "digits" greater than 9 will be in upper-case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `operator.itemgetter` and `operator.attrgetter` within `map` function to do all the codes in one line and use `str.join()` to join the result :

```
from operator import itemgetter,attrgetter
''.join(map(attrgetter('isChecked'),itemgetter(0,1,2,3)(self.allcheckboxes)))
```

Also note that there is no binary type in python, when you get the concatenated string, based on your aim and the functions which you are dialing for, you can tread with this string as a binary number.

For example if you want to convert it to an integer you can use `int` function by passing 2 as its *base*:

```
>>> int('0101',2)
5
```